# I realize Parallel.Invoke with await Task.Run , are there disadvantages or differences?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

```cs
public static async void Start_myMethod1_asyncron()
{
    await Task.Run(() => {
        myMethod1();
    });
}

public static async void Start_myMethod2_asyncron()
{
    await Task.Run(() => {
        myMethod2();
    });
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Start_myMethod1_asyncron();
    Start_myMethod2_asyncron();

    //difference?

    Parallel.Invoke(myMethod1, myMethod2); 
}
```

- Do `Start_myMethod1_asyncron()` and `Start_myMethod2_asyncron()` together do the same as `Parallel.Invoke(myMethod1, myMethod2)`?
- Can I use `asyncron()` Methods to realize parallelism?

Comment: `Task.Run` is basically a more modern version of `Parallel.Invoke`. Tl;Dr typically always use the `Task` abstractions and let it handle the threads for you. In 2021 there isn't much point in using any of the `Parallel` libraries

Comment: Do they "do the same". Well yes and no. There are multiple differences under the hood. But the result is similar.

Comment: Why do you use `async void`? Please prefer `async Task` over `async void` unless they are event handlers.

Answer (score 3):

One significant difference is that `Parallel.Invoke` and other 'Parallel' methods blocks until the work is done. While `async void` is fire-and-forget, and `async Task` returns a task that need to be handled somehow.

Your example should probably return a task and use `Task.WhenAll(myTask1, myTask2).Result` to be equivalent. However, tasks and async methods are assumed to be asynchronously, and may require work to be done on the main thread before completing. This may result in a deadlock if `.Result` is used on the main thread, so a recommendation is to [never block async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Parallel.Invoke is expected to work with regular synchronous methods, so there should be less of a risk for deadlocks. There might also be some difference in scheduling, I know Parallel.For/Foreach have some logic to throttle the parallelism to limit the number of threads used. I'm not sure if `.Invoke` does the same, or what exactly the difference it has compared to the regular scheduling of tasks.

In my opinion, use Parallel for/foreach when running compute heavy, data-parallel work. Use Tasks/async either when doing IO-intensive work, or to avoid blocking the UI thread. I would guess that for Task-parallel work you could use either task/async or Parallel.Invoke, I personally probably prefer tasks.